# WebStorm Turn of Double Guidelines

Tags: ide, coding-style, webstorm

I opened a new project in WebStorm, and I see two guidelines.  One is appears at 80 and the at 120.

I want to keep the guideline at 120 and get rid of the one at 80, but all attempts to tweak settings have yielded nothing.  Any help would be appreciated.

I have:

- Set Visual Guide Settings to 120 (no commas)
- Disabled ESLint
- Disabled Prettier

[image]

Comment: You must have disabled global Visual Guide... but forgot to check language specific ones (yes, Code Style can provide language specific values). For example: `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript | Wrapping and Braces | Visual guides`

Comment: Yeah, that did it.  And you were right- it was only set that way for JS files.

Answer (score 1):

As lazyone mentioned, the solve was:

Settings/Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> Javascript -> Wrapping and Braces -> Visual guides.

[image]